# Cannot read property 'token' of undefined ao receber objeto do localstorage angular

Tags: angular, http, angular-5

Minha função de login guarda no `localstorage` um token retornado da api:

```
  localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
```

Logo após fazer o login, preciso passar esse token para outra função, porém não consigo fazer minha variável receber o token guardado no `localstorage`, tentei algo como:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    this.trocaToken(token);
}
```

Porém, eu recebo:

> Cannot read property 'token' of undefined

Se eu dou um `console.log(localStorage.getItem('token')`, ele printa normalmente meu token, mas não consigo coloca-lo dentro de uma variável.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa declarar a variável `localstorage` antes.
A seguir um exemplo:

```
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    credenciais: any;
    lembrarCredenciais: boolean;

    constructor(
        private localStorage: LocalStorageService
    ) {
        const loginGravado = localStorage.retrieve('credenciais');

        this.lembrarCredenciais = !!loginGravado;
        this.credenciais = Object.assign({}, {
            login: '',
            senha: ''
        }, loginGravado);
    }

    async fazerLogin() {
        try {
            this.form.validate();

            if (this.lembrarCredenciais) {
                this.localStorage.store('credenciais', this.credenciais);
            }
    // ...

}
```

O componte ngx-webstorage foi baixado no `npmjs`